# Makefile.am to run script if source file changed

Tags: autotools, automake

I have a text file **input.in** and a shell script **input.sh** which generates several **.cpp** and **.h** files from it.

I would like **input.sh** to run before building any target but only if **input.in** has been changed or if source files to be generated are missing.

Is there a way to do so in **Makefile.am**?

Comment: Is it a make question or an autotools/automake question?

Comment: It is an **automake** question, I apologize for excess tags, which i now removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `BUILT_SOURCES`.  See [the relevant page of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Built-Sources-Example.html).

The basic idea is that `BUILT_SOURCES` lists source files that must be precomputed -- ones that the ordinary automatic dependency tracking can't figure out.  These sources will be built before regular compilations are done.

Then, you need a rule to actually create these sources.  One idea might be:

```
BUILT_SOURCES = something.c

$(BUILT_SOURCES): input.sh input.in
        $(srcdir)/input.sh -o $@
```